# How can I sort an array according to number of instances of value?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an array in php according to number of occurrence of value.

```
Array(Switzerland,Switzerland,Switzerland,Switzerland,Italy,Italy,Germany,France,France,France)
```

like this ...

```
Array(Switzerland,Switzerland, Switzerland,Switzerland,France,France,France,Italy,Italy,Germany,)
```

Answer (score 6):

For PHP7:

```
<?php

$couuntries = [
    'Switzerland',
    'Italy',
    'Switzerland',
    'France',
    'Switzerland',
    'Italy',
    'Germany',
    'France',
    'France',
    'Switzerland',
];
$counts = array_count_values($couuntries);
usort($couuntries, function($one, $second) use ($counts) {
    return $counts[$second] <=> $counts[$one];
});
print_r($couuntries);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Switzerland
    [1] => Switzerland
    [2] => Switzerland
    [3] => Switzerland
    [4] => France
    [5] => France
    [6] => France
    [7] => Italy
    [8] => Italy
    [9] => Germany
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$someArray = ['aa','aa','b','ccc','ccc','ccc'];

$someArray = array_count_values($someArray); 
arsort($someArray); 
foreach($someArray as $key => $value) 
{
   for ($i = 0; $i<$value; $i++) $result[] = $key; 
}

print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.